# Spring security 3 : Save informations about authentification in database

Tags: java, spring-security

I need to save some informations about user when he is authentificated like his IP Adress and authentification date and other stuff into the database. In other words i want to keep  connections history.
I am using a custom authentification provider, an implementation of UserDetailsService but i dont know where to put code of saving these informations.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` implements `ApplicationEventPublisherAware` and fires the event `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` on successful authentication, you just need to listen to that event and update database. This will keep your database code clean and decoupled from the security code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement your custom [AuthenticationSuccessHandler](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AuthenticationSuccessHandler.html).