# Logout user in custom event listener

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

For Spring Security, I am required to log out a user in `AuthenticationSuccessEvent`.  If the user logs in with valid credentials, I want to log out the user based on some constraints.

How can I do this?

```
@Override
public void onApplicationEvent(AbstractAuthenticationEvent appEvent) {
    if (appEvent instanceof AuthenticationSuccessEvent) {
        if(Condition true)
        {
            //LOGOUT
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you elaborate your usecase? In short you cannot do this in an `ApplicationListener`.

Comment: I want to a block a user for five minutes if he tries to login with wrong credential for 3 times.
So after 3 wrong attempts even user login with right credential it should be logged out.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351391/how-can-i-limit-login-attempts-in-spring-security this has a couple of solutions. Basically you want to prevent this situation, don't allow a succesful login at all after x number of failed logins.

Comment: But i want to stop the user to login for only five minutes.

Comment: For blocking i have count 10 .I am updating my DB and last login also.So if count is 3 and time is less than 5 minutes than i want it to logout even after successful login.

Comment: Next to count, store last login attempt date/time and compare in the dao. As mentioned this cannot be done in an `ApplicationListener`, as the user is already logged in by then and potentially an `ApplicationListener` executes asynchronously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't done this in a `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` yet, but what would try is to do the same thing the [`LogoutFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutFilter.html) does.

Unfortunaly the  `LogoutFilter` does the logout handling directly in its handler method`LogoutFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)`, so it would be a hack to invoke it diretly, (but not impossible)

```
@Autowired
LogoutFilter logoutFilter;


private void doLogout() {
    MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest(
          "GET",
          "http://myApp" + this.logoutFilter.getFilterProcessingUrl());        

    this.logoutFilter.doFilter(request, new MockHttpServletResponse(),
                               new MockFilterChain());
}
```

But this is a hack. -- Anway, I would start with this. It it works, and show that this prove of concept works, then I would implment a more clean solution:

Obain a list of all [`LogoutHandler`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutHandler.html)s that are registered with the [`LogoutFilter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/index.html?org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/LogoutFilter.html) and invoke them directly and then fire `logoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess` (that is exactly what the LogoutFilter does).

```
@Autowired
List<LogoutHandler> logoutHandlers;

@Autwired
LogoutSuccessHandler logoutSuccessHandler;

private void doLogout() {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    for (LogoutHandler handler : handlers)
         handler.logout(request, response, auth);

    logoutSuccessHandler.onLogoutSuccess(request, response, auth);
}
```

---

### BUT

if you only want to prevent the user from login because of some constraints, it would be much easyer and cleaner to implement the interface `UserDetailsChecker` and register you implementation with `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.preAuthenticationChecks` or `.postAuthenticationChecks`  (It is likely that you use `DaoAuthenticationProvider` which is a subclass of `AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`)

(Hint:`void UserDetailsChecker.check(UserDetails toCheck)` (that is the only one method of `UserDetailsChecker`)  - need to throw a Exception if it want to prevent the user from logging in.)

```
 private class Demo implements UserDetailsChecker {
    public void check(UserDetails user) {
        if (!user.isAccountNonLocked())
            throw new LockedException("User account is locked");
        if (!user.isEnabled())
            throw new DisabledException("User is disabled"));
        if (!user.isAccountNonExpired())
            throw new AccountExpiredException("User account has expired");
        //And here comes you!
    }
}
```