# Block user account after 3 consecutive failed login attempts using spring security

Tags: authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

How to save the number of consecutive failed login attempts, and how to block a user account after reaching 3 failed consecutive login attempts?

Can i do that using implementing `AuthenticationFailureHandler`, `ApplicationListener` and `AuthenticationFailureBadCredentialsEvent`? If so how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I limit login attempts in Spring Security?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351391/how-can-i-limit-login-attempts-in-spring-security)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was already discussed in: [How can I limit login attempts in Spring Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351391/how-can-i-limit-login-attempts-in-spring-security)