# spring LDAP does not throw specific error code

Tags: java, spring, ldap

**Environment**

1. LDAP Server: TurnKey OpenLDAP
2. Spring-ldap-core version: 2.3.3.RELEASE

**What is the activity**

1. User is locked in LDAP server
2. User attempts to login through our webapp
3. Login failed
4. Error code 49 - Invalid Credentials is thrown

**What is expected**

Specific exception should be thrown(eg: Error code 775 USER_ACCOUNT_LOCKED)

**Excepion**

Some information like *comment* and *data* are not found in the exception

````
org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]; nested exception is javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials]
    at org.springframework.ldap.support.LdapUtils.convertLdapException(LdapUtils.java:191)```
````

Comment: And what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The [LDAP protocol RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4511) doesn't provide the level of granularity that you want for a rejected authentication request, it's simply error code 49 invalidCredentials. There is no account locked in the standard.

In another [LDAP wiki documentation here](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP%20Result%20Codes) about error codes, it also specifies that error code 49 is valid for locked accounts.

If you are keen on having this functionality you could opt to take control of your security layer and impose a maximum retry count for your application (rather than relying of whatever is default in a third party LDAP server), keep track if it's reached, and throw/return the appropriate response that you want. I can see an example of how you could do that in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5351391/how-can-i-limit-login-attempts-in-spring-security), but I would invest a bit more time in finding the best solution if you want to go this way.

Comment: Thanks you Cristian Toader. What you said is correct.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP specification is base. It defines error codes.
Implementation of LDAP such as OPEN_LDAP, ACTIVE_DIRECTORY etc.. may define its own sub-error codes with exception message. Active Directory supplies its own sub-error codes within the error message.
[ldap-related-rfcs](https://ldap.com/ldap-related-rfcs/)
[active-directory-error-codes](https://dotcms.com/docs/latest/active-directory-error-codes)